# Need to provide workspace as a parameter in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, workspace, jenkins-job-dsl

I am having the condition where I need to use same jenkins file for different jobs, for that I need to give agent and workspace as a parameter by giving this I can use the jenkins file just by entering the agent name and workspace path

how to achieve this?